# Passing custom emited events as props to a new created component in VueJs

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

**My app consists of:**

A component named

```
<consl :output="output" @submit-to-vue><consl>
```

which contains an input that calls a submit() method when enter key is pressed.

```
<div> 
    <output v-html="output"></output>
    <div id="input-line" class="input-line">
        <div class="prompt">{{ prompt }}</div>
        <div>
        <input class="cmdline" autofocus 
            v-model.trim="command" 
            @keyup.enter="submit"  
            :readonly="submited" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then the method `submit()` emits an event `@submit-to-vue` to parent method `submitv()` that create an instance of the same component and adds it to the DOM.

```
//........
methods: {
    submit: function () {
        this.$emit('submit-to-vue')
        this.submited = true
    }
},
```

and

```
//......
methods: {
    submitv: function () {
        var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(consl)
        var instance = new ComponentClass({
            propsData: { output: this.output }
        })
        instance.$mount() // pass nothing
        this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

**What I want to accomplish ?**

I want to create a new consl component and add it to the DOM every time the old one is submited. (I want my app to emulate a terminal)

**The problem**

When submitted the new created component does not contain the `@submit-to-vue` event listener, which make it unable to recall the `submitv()` method.

**Questions**

- How can I solve this problem ?
- Is this the proper way to do things in VueJs or is there a more elegent way ?

Comment: Don't manipulate the DOM yourself, focus on the data and let Vue deal with the DOM.

Comment: Meaning that instead of manually creating a new component and inserting it, just push a new data object to the array that is used to populate the container with a `v-for`.

Comment: isn't it a little bit expensive in memory ?  I mean an array of object won't affect the performance of the app ?

Comment: @M.Iduoad manual DOM manipulation is more expensive, especially when you're essentially trying to override a framework that excels at it. Why even use Vue then?

Comment: In addition to being more efficient, it will solve the event problem you're having. But honestly, if you want to simulate a terminal, just fill the container with the output and keep a single component below for the input, which resets when submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parent component, declare one data property=childs, it will includes all childs already created.

So once parent component receives the event=`submit-to-vue`, then add one new child to `this.childs`

Finally uses `v-for` to render these child components.

**The trick**: always consider the data-driven way, doesn't manipulate dom directly as possible.

**below is one simple demo** :

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('child', {

  template: `
  <div> 
    <div>Label:<span>{{output}}</span></div>
    <div>Value:<span>{{command}}</span></div>
    <div id="input-line" class="input-line">
        <div class="prompt">{{ prompt }}</div>
        <div>
        <input class="cmdline" autofocus 
            v-model.trim="command" 
            @keyup.enter="submit"  
            :readonly="submited" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  props: ['output'],
  data() {
    return {
      submited: false,
      command: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    prompt: function () {
      return this.submited ? 'Already submitted, input is ready-only now' : ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function () {
      this.$emit('submit-to-vue')
      this.submited = true
    }
  }
})

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    childs: [{'output':'default:'}]
  },
  methods: {
    addChild: function () {
      this.childs.push({'output': this.childs.length})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(child, index) in childs" :key="index">
        <child :output="child.output" @submit-to-vue="addChild()"></child>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```